# Add css styling to og: image

Tags: css, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to add CSS styling to a facebook og:image that you would use for a Facebook share? I am not using a static image, but they are dynamic (php)

So, here is my tag in its current state and it just grabs the image for that particular product. But, it is just an image. I want to use CSS to put a coloured block in the top right corner and put some styled text in there for example.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $data['img_name']; ?>" />
```

I am not very familiar with Facebook sharing so not sure if this is possible.

Comment: `og:image` expects a path to an image file, _and only an image file_. If you want to modify the image, this would need to be done before the path is output to the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CSS is a styling language and won't be applied to an image directly. When adjusting this meta-tag it won't be applied to the actual image.

What you can do is dynamically make a different image and add a new object on top of the image and serve this image with the meta tag.

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php